# How to convert from jQuery to fetch API

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I am working on a function

```
String.prototype.isActualWord = function() {
    if ($ != undefined) {
        let str = this.toLowerCase()
        let res = false
            
            const url = "https://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/" + str + "/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=false&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=_THIS_IS_CONFIDENTIAL_";

            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        res = true
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                         res = false
                    }
                })
            }
            catch(e) {
                throw new Error(e.message)
            }
        return res
    } else {
        throw new Error("Please Include jQuery In Your Project")
    }
}
```

Here is the fetch code:

```
let res = false
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    if(data[0] != undefined) {
        res = true
    } 
  });
```

you see, I want to remove the jQuery dependency from my project. how can I achieve this using the asynchronous way using fetch API. i have tried many ways but in vain.

Comment: Can you show us the fetch code you tried?

Comment: @Scruffy updated my question.

Comment: what you got on your request in case you running your fetch analog?

Comment: @PaulZaslavskij when i log the res variable inside the promise `.then()` it shows the updated value but when I try to return it outside that, its value is not updated. and I know its because of asynchronous behaviour of js, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: there are two ways to solve it: 1. move the code, that gonna use your response data inside of .then(). 2. you can got the result using async/await. like `const myValue = await fetch('url').then((res) => res.json())` . but don't forget to make parent function `async`, otherwise it will be impossible to use await statement

Comment: @PaulZaslavskij i tried this: `res = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()).then(data => {
              if(data[0] != undefined) {
               return true
              } else {
               return false
              }
             })` and it returns a pending promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetching of the API is asynchronous so you should wait for it before returning the answer. In the checking you should add async/await too:

```
async function testWord(word) {
    let check = await word.isActualWord();
    return check;
}
```

And to avoid cors issues add init with cors to the fetch api

```
String.prototype.isActualWord = async function() {
  let str = this.toLowerCase()
  let res = false
  let myHeaders = new Headers();
  let myInit = { method: 'GET',
               headers: myHeaders,
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };
      
  const url = "https://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/" + str + "/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=false&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=_THIS_IS_CONFIDENTIAL_";

  try {
    const data = await fetch(url, (myInit as RequestInit))
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    });
      if(data[0] != undefined) {
          res = true
      }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log('there was an error', e)
      throw new Error(e.message)
      }
  return res
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! it finally solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the comments you're looking to use fetch as though it were synchronous.

To achieve this, use the `await` keyword inside an async function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

For example, you might follow this general structure:

```
async function() {
  await fetch(...).then(...);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: can you rewrite my code using an async function? and explain?

Comment: Edited to add an outline.